# jQuery error arise in a slider

Tags: jquery

i have to do  a slider of image and content in my site and i use a jQuery plugin for that slider , but there is a error raised .

jQuery("#one").ContentSlider is not a function

and my code for that

```
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#one').ContentSlider({
      width : '900px',
      height : '400px',
      speed : 800,
      easing : 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  });
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#two').ContentSlider({
      width : '600px',
      height : '266px',
      speed : 400,
      easing : 'easeOutQuad',
      textResize : true
    });
  });
```

i don't know what is problem with the error.

Comment: Please specify which plugin you are using

Comment: Did you include your plugin *after* you included the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens if your Plugin Script isn't loaded correctly... Check the path to the script and if it's loaded or have a look at the manual if ContentSlider is spelled correctly (maybe it's contentslider, contentSlider or ContentSliders....)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with this particular plugin and have experienced the same problem.

This error occurred because you linked the `jquery` library more than once.